# Create one object from another

Tags: javascript

I need to get the output from the below input:

Input Format:

```
var inputParams = { 
    'inputDetails' :[
        { 'field' : 'specificationName', 'value' : 'strong'},
        { 'field' : 'specificationName', 'value' : 'weak'},
        { 'field' : 'specificationName', 'value' : 'energetic'}
        { 'field' : 'incident', 'value' : '123'},
        { 'field' : 'groupId', 'value' : 'g1'},
        { 'field' : 'groupId', 'value' : 'group1'},
    ]
};
```

Output Format:

```
var outputParams = {
    'paramDetail': [
        { 'field' : 'specificationName', 'value' : [ 'strong ', 'weak' ,'energetic']},
        { 'field' : 'incident', 'value' : ['123']},
        { 'field' : 'groupId', 'value' : ['g1', 'group1']},
    ] 
};
```

The logic I have tried is:

```
var changedList = {
                   changedJsonObject : []
                  };
var i = 0 ;
var prev;
var firstTime = true;
var index = 0;
var facetfields = ['strong', 'weak' ,'energetic'];
do {
    if (!params[index].field.localeCompare(facetFields[i])) {
        if (prev == null) {
            prev = params[index].field;
        }
        console.log(index + " " + params[index].field + " " + params[index].value);
        if (!prev.localeCompare(params[index].field)) {
            if (firstTime) {
                console.log("create");
                outputParams.paramDetail.push({
                    "field": params[index].field,
                    "value": [params[index].value]
                });
                firstTime = false;
            } else {
                console.log("update");
                for (var tempInd = 0; tempInd < outputParams.paramDetail.length; tempInd++) {
                    if (!outputParams.paramDetail[tempInd].field.localeCompare
                         (params[index].field)) {
                        outputParams.paramDetail[tempInd].value =
                            outputParams.paramDetail[tempInd].value + "," + params[index].value;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        i++;
        index = index - 1;
        firstTime = true;
        prev = null;
    }
}
index++;
}
while (index < params.length);
for (var s in outputParams.paramDetail) {
    console.log(outputParams.paramDetail[s].field);
    console.log(outputParams.paramDetail[s].value);
}
```

Output of the above code should be:

specificationName
["strong", "weak", "energetic"]
incident
["123"]
groupid
["g1","group1"]

The requirement is the type `value` should be an array of strings. My ultimate goal is to group the values based on field names.

The above code gives me a result, which when I parse is not a proper result.

Comment: `The above code gives me a result, which when I parse is not a proper result.` what does it give you? Post that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Valijon with the javascript for updating array value.

just changed the line of update as given by Valijon. My code is working as expected.

```
outputParams.paramDetail[tempInd].value.push(arr.jsonList1[index].value);
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work only if objects are *sorted*:

```
var outputparams = { 'paramDetail': [] };
var lastGroup = "";

for ( var n = 0; n < inputParams.inputDetails.length; n++ )
{
     if ( lastGroup !=  inputParams.inputDetails[n].field )
     {
         outputparams.paramDetail.push({ 'field': inputParams.inputDetails[n].field, 'value': [] });
         lastGroup = inputParams.inputDetails[n].field;
     }
     var currentField = outputparams.paramDetail.length -1;

     outputparams.paramDetail[currentField].value.push(inputParams.inputDetails[n].value);

}
```

currently not tested, but that's what I would start with.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var inputParams = { 
    "inputDetails" : [
        { "field" : "specificationName", "value" : "strong"},
        { "field" : "specificationName", "value" : "weak"},
        { "field" : "specificationName", "value" : "energetic"},
        { "field" : "incident", "value" : "123"},
        { "field" : "groupId", "value" : "g1"},
        { "field" : "groupId", "value" : "group1"}
    ]
};

var outputParams = {
    "paramDetail" : []
};

for(i=0;i<inputParams.inputDetails.length;i++){
    exist = false;
    for(j=0;j<outputParams.paramDetail.length;j++){
        if(outputParams.paramDetail[j].field == inputParams.inputDetails[i].field){
            outputParams.paramDetail[j].value.push(inputParams.inputDetails[i].value);
            exist = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!exist){
        outputParams.paramDetail.push({"field" : inputParams.inputDetails[i].field, "value" : [inputParams.inputDetails[i].value]});
    }
}

console.log(outputParams);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I have used up your code for updating the type value and my logic worked.

But your logic gives the same list again

Answer (score 0):

Try the following function to process `inputParams`

```
var process = function (input) {
    var results = {};
    input.inputDetails.forEach(function (value, key) {
        if (!(value.field in results)) results[value.field] = [];
        results[value.field].push(value.value);
    });
    var output = { paramDetail : [] };
    for (key in results) {
        output.paramDetail.push({
            field: key,
            value: results[key]
        });
    }
    return output;
};

var outputParams = process(inputParams);
```